# using boost::unordered_map as a look up table appears to be extremely slow

Tags: c++, boost, unordered-map, lookup-tables

I have the following look up table defined:

```
boost::unordered_map<std::string, STFRandomTreeFunctor*> functor_look_up_table;
```

the idea is to use it to call the functor, however this appears to be running very slow. At first I thought it was because the function that the functor calls may be taking a long time to run, I replaced the code as follows (i.e. removed the call to `functor()`):

```
my_function(){
    while(...){
        STFRandomFunctor* f = functor_look_up_table.at(some_string);
        ...<do some other stuff>
    }
}
```

and it still runs slow, the removal of the line `STFRandomFunctor* f = functor_look_up_table.at(some_string);` speeds up the code immensely. Am I using the wrong kind of data structure for my look up table here? If so, what is preferable?

Comment: What do your keys(`std::string`) look like? Its possible that your getting the worse case runtime because of the default hash function.

Comment: can you profile it to see how much time you're spending in the hash function, and how much elsewhere?

Comment: How long your strings are? Hashing a long string may be expensive. Also depending on the nature of your strings, default hash function may not work very well and you get many collisions. Are all your strings known at compile time? if yes, did you consider using integer keys rather than strings?

Comment: @aleguna strings are id's for functions, some examples are "single_channel_subtract_abs", "multi_channel_random_add", "multi_channel_random_subtract_abs". There are 5 keys in total

Comment: @aleguna strings are known at compile time, I will try int keys now... brb

Comment: With five keys, an unordered_set is overkill. Just do a linear search in an array of strings.

Comment: @Aly, and while you doing that, drop the unordered_map and use an array with access by int index, index being an id of your function

Comment: I think you are misdiagnosing the problem.  When you remove the line that looks up the function you are also disabling or skipping something else which is taking most of the time.  The rest of your loop would have to be extremely trivial (it almost certainly isn't) for the map lookup to be significant.  To bisect the problem temporarily swap the boost::unordered_map for a std::map, and see what effect that has.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling the rest of the loop is trivial, the main chunk is calling the function that the functor contains. Granted the function does take up time, but as displayed just getting the functor (without calling the function) is taking an abnormal amount of time,

Comment: How can you tell the difference between the lookup time and the time it takes to execute the functor?

Comment: @aleguna changing to int seems to have sped it up, please post an answer and I will accept <at>Pete Becker I will switch to arrays now that I am using int keys.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling by removing the lines  `STFRandomFunctor* f = functor_look_up_table.at(some_string); f();` I can know how long it takes without doing either, and then by removing the line `f()` I can see the reduction in time by not calling the function but still retrieving the functor

Comment: Better use profiler for such purposes

Comment: @DenisErmolin Indeed it is better, but this is quicker and gives an indication of what is taking time. Granted if the loop was doing more, a profiler would be much simpler

Comment: Well the difference in time between a large (direct access) array lookup and a large hash table lookup of a string key is about ~100 nanosecs vs ~1 microsecs.  It should only become significant if you are doing > 10^5 iterations of the loop per second.

Comment: Are you sure you are measuring what you think you are measuring? For example if you remove the lookup in the map and replace it with a single functor call, it may be that the compiler can just inline the whole functor then which it couldn't do before as it didn't know which one you would call.

Comment: How many iterations per second of the loop do you observe and expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> @aleguna strings are id's for functions, some examples are "single_channel_subtract_abs", "multi_channel_random_add", "multi_channel_random_subtract_abs". There are 5 keys in total

Then you should not be using a string, nor a `unordered_map`:

```
// Function.hpp

enum FunctorName {
    single_channel_subtract_abs,
    multi_channel_random_add,
    multi_channel_random_substract_abs,
    ...
};

STFRandomTreeFunctor const& get(FunctorName name);

// Function.cpp
static STFRandomTreeFunctor const Functors[] = {
    ...
};

STFRandomTreeFunctor const& get(FunctorName name) {
    size_t const index = name;

    assert(index < sizeof(Functors) && "Need to update Functors");

    return Functors[index];
} // get
```

You may drop the `const&` in `get` altogether if `STFRandomTreeFunctor` is a `typedef` for a function type and not a full blown functor.

Answer (score 0):

`unordered_map` are extremely fast at lookup, but if you have a good hashing function, every time that you look at your map, hash of your key will be computed, so if computing hash take long time, then your performance is poor, on the other hand if `hash` function generate similar `hash` values may all(or a lot of) items fall in one bucket and then your search become linear, for first part your string must be really huge to default hash of the `boost` take a long time, but for second part, try changing bucket size and check performance again.

Comment: This is a comment then answer